# List won't show when the Button is pressed (+String parameter 'genre' is not present)

Tags: java, html, button, web-development-server, white-labelling

This is my first time using StackOverflow, I apologize for any mistakes in the summary of the question.

I'm trying to create a `button` for a video catalog webpage that when pressed returns the films with the fitting genre. The movies are `static` and all have a genre assigned to them already, like genre = 'Action' which is returned as a `String` in a function named `getGenre()`.
I made a function that checks if each movie has a genre and then puts them in the list filtered which is then returned as the "catalog" (I will present the function code below).

I know filtered contains all the movies at the moment but I wanted to make it work that when the `button` is pressed it checks the string genre in the HTML file for the specific genre and then returns the right movies.

**filter function:**

```
@PostMapping("/genre")
  String dvdCatalog(Model model, @RequestParam("genre") String genre ) {

    Iterable<Disc> dvdList = catalog.findByType(DiscType.DVD);
    List<Disc> filtered = new ArrayList<Disc>();

    
    for (Iterator<Disc> iterator = catalog.findByType(DiscType.DVD).iterator();
         iterator.hasNext(); )
    {
        Disc disc = iterator.next();
        if (disc.getGenre().equals(genre))
        {
            filtered.add(disc);
        }
    }

    model.addAttribute("catalog", filtered);
    model.addAttribute("title", "catalog.bluray.title");

    return "catalog";
```

In my corresponding HTML file, I made the 'Action' button and when checking the webpage it works alright until I press the Action button. I'm really new to Web Development and don't know a lot about how it works, when pressed I get a Whitelabel Error Page, I will show it below.

**html button:**

```
<form method="post" class="ui form" id="form" th:action="@{/genre}" >
    <button type="submit" class="ui button" th:value="'Action'" th:text="Action" id="genre"></button>
</form>
```

**Whitelabel Error:**

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400). Required
> String parameter 'genre' is not present
> org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:
> Required String parameter 'genre' is not present at
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:204)

My question is: Why is my `String` parameter not present even though I am checking for it in the HTML? I am out of ideas with how to make this work, I have no idea why it can't find the genre parameter.

If someone knows could you please show me how it's done? I want to understand and learn from this, it's frustrating

Thanks

**EDIT:** changing id = "genre" to name = "genre" has fixed the issue of finding the parameter (thanks so much for that, really) but when I press the button now it shows me a blank page with just the button, what happened there? How can I make it return my list?

Comment: I think your button needs `name="genre"`, not `id`.

Comment: you were right, thank you so much the page finally shows, but it's empty when it should return the movies with the fitting genre. Do you have an idea why that is?

Comment: First thing to check is that your list `filtered` actually contains some data. You could add a system.out.println or attach a debugger to see what's happening.